# Let a and b be integers. If $a+b$ is even, either $a$ or $b$ is even

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm having some trouble proving or disproving this statement. I was able to find that it was true for $a^2 + b^2$ (where both have to be even). Is it the same for $a+b$?

Comment: Generally, $a+b$ is even if and only if $a$ and $b$ have the same parity.

Comment: One of the first things people learn in math is $1+1=2$

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong!

For example: $$5+7=12$$

Answer (score 1):

Both of them is wrong;
Counter-example:

- $a=1$ is odd;
- $b=1$ is odd;
- **but** both of $a^2+b^2=2=a+b$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a and b odd numbers. Then:

a= 2k+1;
b= 2l+1

$a^2 + b^2 = (2k+1)^2 + (2l+1)^2= 4k^2 + 4k + 1 + 4l^2 +4l +1 = 4(k^2+l^2+k+l)+2$ => even number

a+b= 2k+1 + 2l+1 = 2(k+l+1) => even number

For a,b even: a=2k; b=2l

$a^2+b^2= 4(k^2 + l^2)$ => even

a+b= 2(k+l) => even